# OpenLayers - Mercator projection, with decimal degree lat/lon units

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers to display a map of the same projection as Google Maps, Bing, etc. (that is, a square Mercator map). As I understand it, to enable this projection, I need to use the sphericalMercator flag. However, this also appears to change the units used by the LonLat method, etc. such that I have to transform from decimal degrees to metres.

Is there a way I can use the Mercator projection, but still use decimal degrees in order to specify positions on the map?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "specifying positions on the map": if you want to add Markers, Vector Features etc., you have to re-project their coordinates, but you can do [that within OpenLayers](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html#working-with-projected-coordinates).

If you just want specify positions in a "read-only way" (e.g. displaying the current mouse position with the MousePosition Control in a certain coordinate system), you can do so by simply specifying the ["displayProjection" parameter of the map.](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html#display-projection-on-controls)

Comment: I meant when adding markers and features. So there is no way to have OpenLayers know that I'm specifying degrees rather than metres, and perform the projection itself? I've written some utility functions to make this straightforward (based on the OpenLayer projection transforms) but I'd prefer not to have to for clarity.

Comment: I'm afraid, that this isn't possible, since it's not just about metres or degrees: there are hundreds of metric coordinate systems out there, so OpenLayers can't just rely on the coordinate units for an accurate projection. At the first glance this seems unnecessary work, but its the only way to project GIS data in different coordinate systems accurately on the map.